# Prove that $f(x,y)$ is integrable.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\subset \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, define by  $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } 0\le x< \dfrac{1}{2}; \\
1, & \text{ if }  \dfrac{1}{2}\le x\le 1 
\end{cases}$$
Prove that $f$ is integrable and $\displaystyle \int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}f=1/2$.

**Solution:**

I have seen in books that consider the following partition, $P=(P_1,P_2)$ where $P_1=P_2=\{0,1/2,1\}$. And they say that $U(f,P)=L(f,P)=1/2$ but I have tried to calculate it and I don't know how they do to arrive at that is $1/2$. Could someone help me to complete that step. Thank you very much.

Comment: $P$ divides the domain into four sub-rectangles, right? Can you describe the equations or coordinates of each of those rectangles? Can you determine the lower and upper bounds of $f$ inside each rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

it might be worth simplifying first my saying:
$$\iint\limits_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int\limits_0^1dy\int\limits_0^1f(x)\,dx$$
now you only have two partitions to consider: $(0,1/2),(1/2,1)$. To perform a sanity check that your method gives the right answer you can say:
$$\int_0^1f\,dx=\int_0^{1/2}f\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1 f\,dx=\int_0^{1/2}0\,dx+\int_{1/2}^11\,dx=(1-1/2)=1/2$$